# Is it possible to override the filetype of a text file based on the first line?

Tags: vimscript, highlight, syntax, ftdetect

I have some specifically formatted text files that I'd like to detect when I start vim. When I load these files now, the filetype is automatically set to text. I only want to override that if the first line of the text file starts with "Client:", in which case, I'd like to set the filetype to veltxt. I have already created a syntax file that works with these files.

Here's my `veltxt.vim` from my `ftdetect` folder:

```
if did_filetype()       " filetype already set..  
  finish                " ..don't do these checks  
endif  
if getline(1) =~ '^Client:..*'  
  setfiletype veltxt  
endif
```

Comment: Take a look in $VIMRUNTIME (I think script.vim)

Comment: Hi the `.` (period) after the `:` isn't doing anything If `Client:` is the whole line then `if getline(1) =~ '^Client:$'`matches, assuming you don't have `set ignorecase` in `_vimrc`

Comment: @Steve Single "dot" matches any character (i.e. **not** end of a source string) what makes sense; "dot-star" always matches, so it's an excess.

Comment: @matt thanks however in this case it matched nothing as the string wasn't followed by anything except the `$` EOL which is why I asked

Comment: @Steve If the whole string were "Client:" then it would not have matched regex "^Client:."

Comment: The first line of the file always starts with "Client:", but there should always be something after that, hence the ".*" For example, "Client: Sam".

Comment: @sam Alleman Fair enough. Your example didn't match the regex as it ended at the `:`. No worries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to set the filetype based on the contents of the file.

If you add a script to the `ftdetect` directory, this script should set up a new `autocmd` to trigger when a file of a specific extension or file name pattern (or `*` if any file name is possible) is opened and then set the appropriate filetype there.

The `autocmd` can then set the filetype in a few different ways:

- Using the [`setfiletype` (`setf`) command](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%3Asetfiletype), which will set the filetype, but *only if it wasn't set yet.*
- Using the `setf FALLBACK` command, which sets the filetype, but allows later `setf` commands to override it.
- Using the `setlocal filetype=...` command to update the [`'filetype'` setting](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27filetype%27) directly, which will override any previous settings.

In your case, since the `ftdetect` rules run last, you'll want to use the `setlocal filetype=...` variation.

So, assuming you're matching files that start with `Client:` on their first line and that have any extension whatsoever, you could have a `ftdetect/veltxt.vim` with the following rule:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if getline(1) =~ '^Client:' | setlocal filetype=veltxt | endif
```

Note that you don't need to use an `augroup` in an `ftdetect` script, since Vim already takes care of running all the `ftdetect` scripts within the context of a `filetypedetect` group (see `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` for details, also where `ftdetect/*.vim` are sourced.)

You can adapt the rule above to match specific file patterns, or perhaps check that the previously set `&filetype` match the expected `text` before you inspect the file contents.

See [`:help ftdetect`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ftdetect) for the Vim help documentation on the procedure of configuring new file type detection.

Comment: Yeah! That did it! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You can create `$HOME/.vim/scripts.vim` of your own, as `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` will source it by executing `:runtime! scripts.vim` if needed. It's enough to put only these lines:

```
if getline(1) =~# '^Client:.'
    setf veltxt
endif
```

Note that `.*` at the end of a pattern does nothing (always matches).